# "Sort-Object email -Unique" and if there is duplicate leave the one with the higher role and remove the rest

Tags: powershell

`Sort-Object email -Unique` if there is duplicate leave the one with the higher role and remove the rest.

I think I am going to have to do something like this instead of the `sort-object`

```
$results = $results | foreach-object {

    If ($results.email -contains $_.email) {
        Foreach ($role in $results) {
            <Find my place in the array then replace with the highest role using a switch>
        }
    } 
}

$results = $results Sort-Object email -Unique
```

This seems like I am being too complicated and the results don't work out.
I am here for advice on how to do this. I will expand the middle section of my code if there is not a better way to do this ?

Comment: What constitutes a highest role? What is the type of the input objects?

Comment: I could give a role tree. it goes manager, editor, commenter, viewer
The ```$results``` has 3 fields in it.  Email, role and type (meaning group or person)
I am trying to bring it down to unique email addresses with the highest role and forget the other dupes.

Comment: If you find yourself iterating and immediately using an `if` expression, you should really be filtering _then_ iterating with `Where-Object { ... } | ForEach-Object {`

Comment: Additionally, you're checking whether the email of an item is in the collection of emails of all items, which will _always_ be `$true`.

Comment: Sort based on multiple conditions: `$results | Sort-Object role, email | Select-Object email -Unique` (might need `email, role` play around with it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your goal is to get the highest-roled email where emails can be duplicated, you want to ensure you sort by email, then role, and select out the unique emails:

```
$results |
    Sort-Object -Property role, email |
    Select-Object -Property email -Unique
```

This assumes your object shape is:

```
[pscustomobject]@{
  email = 'string'
  role = 'string'
  type = 'string'
}
```

Comment: Nice, though _alphabetical_ sorting by role probably won't work, if I interpret @dcaz' comments correctly; you'll need a map (hashtable) that associates the role strings with weights:
`$map = @{ manager = 4; editor = 3; commenter = 2; viewer = 1 }` and `$results | Sort-Object email, { $map[$_.role] } | Select-Object email -Unique`

Answer (score 0):

For me the answer worked out like the following. I needed to keep the other properties and always keep any duplicate with the highest role.
I could discard any duplicate less then the higher role.

```
$map = @{ ManagerORcontentManager = 3; writer = 2; commenter = 1 }

$results | Sort-Object email,{ $map[$_.role] } | Group-Object email | ForEach-Object { $_.Group[0] } |  Sort-Object email | Export-Csv C:\Reports\$sharedrivename.csv -NoTypeInformation
```